# Trig/Vector question

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, vector-analysis

I have no idea where to go from here. I only know how to compute dot product, cross product, cos(theta), magnitude, projection, and scalar components but I don't know how to do this

[image: Word Problem]

This is as far as I've gotten so far in trying to wrap my head around this after watching numerous videos on youtube:

[image: Triangle with vectors]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Horizontal component of a vector $V$ is $|V| cos(\theta)$.
Hint 2: Take your horizontal direction to be parallel to inclined plane.

Note that angle of F with inclined plane is $34^\circ-16^\circ = 18^\circ$.

Comment: I don't understand what it is exactly they're asking me for. Are they saying the force of w must be 2.8lb?

Comment: I guess they want you to find w so that component of w parallel to inclined plane is 2.8 lb.

Comment: W is a the vector of force pulling the box. It will never be parallel? Do they want me to find a new vector that will be parallel?

Comment: @Samuel Uribe, it looks like you are aware that you can work with forces as vectors. Now, you have force $w$ pulling in the shown direction. As a two dimensional vector, $w$ can be written uniquely as sum of a vector $u$ parallel to the inclined plane and $u^\perp$ that is perpendicular to the inclined plane: $w = u+u^\perp$. They want you to find $w$ such that $|u| = 2.8\,\mathrm{lb}$.

Answer (score 0):

This was a lot easier than I expected.

$$|w|cos(16°)=2.8$$
will then be
$$|w|=\frac{2.8}{cos(16°)}$$ 
$$|w|=2.91$$